# ErrorException : array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, seeders

Estou com um problema nessa função que me gera um polyline de latitude e longitude.
Porem sempre que executo a seed do Laravel me gera o seguinte erro:
`php  ErrorException  : array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array,string given`

A função que eu chamo dentro da Seed é a seguinte:

```php
    public function gerarPolyline()
    {
        $fake = \Faker\Factory::create('pt_BR');
        $polyline = ['latitude' =>'' , 'longitude' => '' ];

       for($i =0; $i < 1000; $i++){

            $latitude = $fake->latitude($min = -90, $max = 90);
            $longitude = $fake->longitude($min = -180, $max = 180);
            array_push($polyline['latitude'], $latitude);
            array_push($polyline['longitude'],$longitude);
        }
        return $polyline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece pois o `array_push()` está esperando dois argumentos. Mude seu código assim:

```
public function gerarPolyline()
    {
        $fake = \Faker\Factory::create('pt_BR');
        $polyline = ['latitude' =>'' , 'longitude' => '' ];

       for($i =0; $i < 1000; $i++){

            $latitude = $fake->latitude($min = -90, $max = 90);
            $longitude = $fake->longitude($min = -180, $max = 180);
            array_push($this->$polyline['latitude'], $latitude);
            array_push($this->$polyline['longitude'],$longitude);
        }
        return $polyline;
    }
```

Comment: Realmente foi isso que aconteceu,Muito obrigado, passou, porem gerou um `ErrorException : Array to string conversion`, e dando dd($latitude), me é retornado algo como: 42.878878 ou uma latitude aleatória, não entendo porque não esta realizando o push.